# I am unable to connect the replicaset db in mongodb compass? when using Direct Connection only works

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to connect my replica set with MongoDB compass since my application string is not working..

I have 3 instances of mongodb

[image]

```
mongoSet [direct: primary] test> rs.status()
{
  set: 'mongoSet',
  date: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:40.508Z"),
  myState: 1,
  term: Long("2"),
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long("2000"),
  majorityVoteCount: 2,
  writeMajorityCount: 2,
  votingMembersCount: 3,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 3,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.301Z"),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.301Z"),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.301Z")
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }),
  electionCandidateMetrics: {
    lastElectionReason: 'electionTimeout',
    lastElectionDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T04:06:38.199Z"),
    electionTerm: Long("2"),
    lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long("-1") },
    lastSeenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1680266171, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    numVotesNeeded: 2,
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    electionTimeoutMillis: Long("10000"),
    numCatchUpOps: Long("0"),
    newTermStartDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T04:06:38.211Z"),
    wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T04:06:38.284Z")
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: 'mongo1:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 4332,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.301Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.301Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:38.983Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:39.159Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: 'mongo2:27017',
      syncSourceId: 1,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 2
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'mongo2:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 4335,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.301Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.301Z"),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1680321998, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T04:06:38.000Z"),
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 2,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'mongo3:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 4333,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.301Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:31.301Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:38.983Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-04-01T05:18:39.026Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: 'mongo2:27017',
      syncSourceId: 1,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 2
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1680326311, i: 1 })
}
```

I am able to connect through studio 3T

[image]

Can I use mongodb://localhost:30001/?directConnection=true in environment variable to connect app? Is Direct Connection safe?

The problem here is i want to see all the 3 nodes ..but direct connection allows only one host.. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect with this connection string:

```
mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017/?replicaSet=mongoSet
```

See [Connection String URI Format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Comment: It is not connecting. It saying eaddress not found mongo1

Comment: Where did you define the hostnames?

Comment: I have  mongo1 mongo2 mongo3 as localhost in etc/hosts.

Comment: This cannot work. You cannot listen to a port with more than one process. Looks like you use Docker, I have no clue about it. How do you publish the port in docker to your local machine?

Comment: after adding etc/hosts working..